# Amazon Cognito: invalid_client when refreshing token

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get a new **accessToken** and **idToken** by hitting the endpoint **oauth2/token**.

I got the refresh token from **cognitoUser.authenticateUser()** method in *amazon-cognito-identity-js*

Here's my sample request in postman:

**URL** (seems fine)

[image: URL]

**BODY** (seems fine)
[image: Postman body]

**HEADERS** (not sure)
[image: Authorization]

Authorization: Basic **Base64(client_id)** - *i used btoa() function in JS*

Note: The pool does not have a client secret
[image: no client secret]

Problem: When I test this out, this is the response
[image: invalid]

I believe I supplied the right data as documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

> grant_type: refresh_token
> client_id: required if does not have a secret
> refresh_token: refresh token here

Is there something that I'm missing or something I did wrong? I am not very familiar with the flow. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer that worked for me was [Shameen's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76610711/11766590)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after checking the [Postman console](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/troubleshooting-api-requests/) and comparing it to the [Token Endpoint Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) i saw it was missing `client_id` in the request body, so I added it in **Authorization -> Advanced -> Refresh Request**:

[image: Key: client_id, Value: ((postman variable for client_id)), Send In: Request Body]

Answer (score 0):

Authorization Basic should be Base64(**client_id:client_secret**)

Comment: but OP doesn't have client_secret, can you update the answer?

Comment: He has to create another Client App and check to the box Enable Client Secret. But with this approach, he has to do this implementation in server side, not client side.